# Pipe input in chunks using bash

Tags: bash, pipe, chunks

I have a bash script which, as part of a pipeline, will be producing large amounts of binary data. I would like to repeatedly call another process with fixed-size chunks of this data on standard input, and collect the results. As an example:

```
cat /dev/urandom | split-input 1048576 md5sum | cut -c1-32
```

The above would produce a list of md5sums of one-megabyte chunks from /dev/urandom.

Is there a bash construct that can accomplish this without dumping the data to variables? Is there already a utility program that does this?